# sed - print and branch

Tags: sed

I have an input stream containing strings representing file types.  I want to print all file types that are not text **or** are PostScript (PostScript is a text file type).  I tried the following sed expression:

```
sed -n '/PostScript/pb; /text/!p'
```

However, this returns an error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 14: extra characters after command
```

This is confusing to me because I thought it was acceptable to specify multiple commands (e.g. `bp`) after a pattern.

I can get the behavior I want using the following expression:

```
sed -n '/PostScript/p; /PostScript/b; /text/!p'
```

How can I get the behavior I want without duplicating the `/PostScript/` pattern in my expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common way to get a group of commands executed together
(e.g., subject to a condition like a pattern match)
is to group them with curly braces.
With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -n '/PostScript/{p; b}; /text/!p'
```

---

Without grouping and with any `sed` branch to end of script in both cases and delete the other lines:

```
sed -e '/PostScript/b' -e '/text/!b' -e 'd'
```

---

Also, for the record:

> I thought it was acceptable to specify multiple commands (e.g. `bp`)
>   after a pattern.

Editing commands for an address (what you call pattern is a context address) are one thing and the `s`ubstitution flags `g`,`p`,`w` and `no.` are another thing.

The  syntax for the latter is

```
s/pattern/replacement/[flags]
```

in other words flags can be combined (e.g. `gp` or `7w outfile`) while the syntax for the former is

```
[2addr] {editing command
editing command
...
}
```

in other words commands must be separated by newlines (in some cases they can be separated by semicolons).

Comment: thanks, after seeing your answer and then reading through the sed documentation again, this is now obvious! can't believe I didn't think of it before :P

Answer (score 3):

POSIXly:

```
$ sed -n '/PostScript/p; //b
/text/!p'
```

[POSIX define](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_02) that if regular expression is empty, `sed` shall behave as if the last RE used in the last command applied.

---

With your command, you need `;` between `p` and `b` to make it work with GNU sed:

```
$ sed -n '/PostScript/p; //b; /text/!p'
```

With POSIX sed, you can't use `//b;` because `;` is a valid branch name. You need to use newline as terminator between command.

Comment: `sed -n '/PostScript/p;b;  /text/!p'` doesn't work for me with `GNU sed version 4.1.5`.  This expression only prints lines that contain the pattern `PostScript` (presumably because it unconditionally branches to the end of the expression after running `/PostScript/p`).

Comment: thanks, the quick edits made it a bit tricky to write accurate comments :) in any case `sed -n '/PostScript/p; //b; /text/!p'` is what has been working for me.

Comment: @jayhendren: And it only works with GNU sed. `;` was considered a valid branch name in POSIX sed.